# Completar casas decimais ",00" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decimal, valor-monetário

Gente eu tenho a seguinte função que estou utilizando pra usar mascara de Moeda

```html
<input class="valr-parc" type="text" name="valr-parc" />

<script>
    String.prototype.Moeda = function() {
        var v = this;
        v = v.replace(/\D/g,'')
        v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1,$2")
        v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')
        v = v.replace(/^(\d)/g,"R$ $1")
        return v;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(view) {
    var valr_parc  = document.getElementsByClassName("valr-parc")[0];


    valr_parc.onkeyup =  function(){
        this.value = this.value.Moeda();
    };

})(this);
</script>
```

Só que eu queria implementar nessa função .Moeda o seguinte: Quando eu digitar apenas um número (ex: 1) ele retornar "R$ 1,00" (atualmente retorna "R$ 1") e quando eu digitar 2 números (ex: 11) ele retornar "R$ 1,10" (atualmente retorna "R$ 1,1) daí a partir dessas duas condições ele já pode começar a rodar do jeito que está (ex: se digitar "111" retorna "R$ 1,11"; digitar "1111" > "R$ 11,11").

Ah, caso tenham uma função diferente (que sirva do mesmo jeito), pode mandar, mas por favor mande algum exemplo online pra testar via input (sem ser pelo "alert" ou "console", manda nesse mesmo esquema que eu mandei) pq eu eu não sei chamar a função em outros moldes (tipo "function (numero) {...")

Answer (score 4):

A solução mais simples seria a utilização da função `toFixed`.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
var numero = 1;

console.log(numero.toFixed(2));
```

Atenção que esta função arredonda os números em alguns casos.
Veja este exemplo.

```js
var numero = 1.567;
console.log(numero.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Convertendo números para moeda sem framework**

É possível converter Number para String `currency` nativo, usando apenas a função `toLocaleString()`. Veja:

```
(10.9).toLocaleString(); // "10,90"
(1002.5).toLocaleString("pt-BR"); // "1.002,50"
(5.55).toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
  // Ajustando casas decimais
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,  
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

O melhor disso, é que dessa forma você evita fazer as gambiarras clássicas em usar `Math.abs()` ou `Number.prototype.toFixed()` do JavaScript.

E outro detalhe legal, esta seguro contra o bug do ponto flutuante:

```
// Resultado bugado
0.1+0.2 // 0.30000000000000004
// Resultado sem bugs
(0.1+0.2).toLocaleString(); // "0.3"
```

---

Exemplo funcional para seu código:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#verifica").on('click', function(){
      var val = new Number ($(".valr-parc").val());
        alert((val).toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
           minimumFractionDigits: 2,  
           maximumFractionDigits: 2
        }));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valr-parc" type="text" name="valr-parc" />
<button id="verifica">Verificar</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darlei_Zillmer/uxhdksLq/)

Veja mais em [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Man, n sei como usar isso aí (tentei e não consegui) :/ Manda um exemplo com input igual está no meu atualmente, daí vc manda com as alterações