# Ajustar valor de centavos

Tags: javascript, matemática

Eu tenho uma variável com a seguinte informação: 100.3

Qual a alternativa melhor para tornar 100.3 para 100.03?

Comment: Isso não faz muito sentido, pelo menos não é arredondamento, isto muda o valor completamente e faz o oposto de arredondar.

Comment: @Maniero Ok, qual a melhor alternativa se eu tiver que tomar essa solução?

Comment: Perceba que `100.3` e `100.03` são valores completamente diferentes (se fossem valores monetários, por exemplo, seria uma diferença de 27 centavos, bem longe de ser um "arredondamento"). Poderia **[edit]** a pergunta e deixar um pouco mais claro que está tentando fazer e se possível colocar mais alguns exemplos de números e seus respectivos resultados? Talvez com um pouco mais de contexto a gente consiga entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Por que precisa disto? Parece não fazer sentido e provavelmente é a solução errada.

Comment: para isso so precisa fazer n=n.replace(".",".0"); , mas sem sentido essa operacao

Comment: Caras, estou trabalhando com um valor, $186.9, queria retornar, 186.09 qual a dificuldade de entender a pergunta?

Comment: @Josimara qual a dificuldade de responder as perguntas que nós fizemos para você?

Comment: @Maniero acabei de responder.

Comment: Onde? Não achei essa resposta.

Comment: Até da pra entender o que quer fazer, mas não está dando pra entender um exemplo prático pois é completamente diferente `168.9` de `168.09`. Não está buscando `168.90`?

Comment: @Renan basicamente isso, não estou sabendo explixar poque nunca trabalhei com esse tipo de valor antes...

Comment: Nós entendemos o que vc quer fazer, só estamos achando estranho a necessidade de fazer isso, pois sem um contexto maior, parece ser uma operação sem sentido. *Talvez* vc esteja tentando resolver um problema e pensou que esta solução é o melhor jeito, mas pode ser que exista uma solução melhor, e por isso pedi que editasse colocando um pouco mais de contexto (em outras palavras, posso até estar enganado, mas *parece* um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/112052)). Não leve a mal nossos questionamentos, todos estão tentando ajudar da melhor forma possível.

Comment: @hkotsubo entendo, mas vocês tem que saber que nem sempre uma pessoa vai conseguir se expressar corretamente se esta vindo a um fórum pegar um help

Comment: @Josimara Eu entendo perfeitamente que nem sempre é fácil explicar um problema. Por outro lado, vc tem que entender que se a pessoa não consegue se expressar corretamente, nem todos irão entender o que ela está querendo dizer, e consequentemente pedirão mais detalhes e esclarecimentos. Faz parte... :-)

Comment: @Josimara é muito simples dizer porque precisa fazer isto, você está evitando porque provavelmente esta é uma solução errada para o problema. E sós estamos querendo, infrutiferamente, ajudar a resolver o real problema.

Comment: @Maniero Psé tinha um erro, primeiro o erro começo comigo mesmo... mas achei uma solução, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251509/completar-casas-decimais-00-javascript

Comment: @Josimara Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

É matemática pura (não precisa fazer gambiarras com *string*, não faz sentido realizar conversões caras que faz mais de uma alocação de memória sem necessidade, fora que a semântica ser incorreta, as pessoas precisam parar de fazer o que apenas funciona e entender o que está fazendo e tomar decisões **corretas**). Seria isto, apesar de não fazer sentido:

```js
var valor = 100.3;
var inteiro = Math.trunc(valor);
console.log(inteiro + ((valor - inteiro) / 10));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/CentsReduce.js).

Comment: Já usei com matemática, achei que encontraria algo mais profundo, mas valeu!

Comment: no lugar do Math.trunc pode ser usado parseInt() que da no mesmo.

Comment: @HudsonPH eu só faço gambiarras onde tem vantagem, se a semântica é toda de valores não vou envolver uma função que foi feita pra lidar com *string* e por uma falha filosófica da linguagem coincidentemente funciona. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png

Comment: @Maniero apenas um exemplo, afinal trunc é apenas (n - n % 1) e resto validacoes

Comment: Na verdade oque eu precisava era de um valor.toFixed(2), pode me corrigir se a função tiver errada...

Comment: @Josimara pode ser, mas sua pergunta não tem informações sobre isto, não temos como saber o que quer. Desde o começo suspeitávamos que ela estava errada.

Answer (score 6):

So fazer isso:

```js
var n = 100.3;
n=n.toString().replace(".",".0");
console.log(n);
```